# interrupted printing

Tags: 12.04, usb, printing, hp

I have a HP Deskjet 720C printer plugged into an Ubuntu 12.04.1 Laptop.

When I plugged the printer for the first time, the system found the right model automatically and everything seemed to be fine. But every time I try to print something, the printing process doesn't finish, the paper stays in the tray half-way, or just about to finish, failing to print the last few lines of a document, and can only be taken out by switching the printer on and off. The printing job shows as interrupted in the printer menu:

[image]

Any ideas on what might be happening?

The printer was previously working fine on an old 7.10 computer via a 25 pin parallel connection. Since then -- and I don't know if this related to the printing problem -- I bought a USB cable adapter to plug to the laptop, like the one in the picture:

[image]

This is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 5213.987345] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 0 alt 1 proto 2 vid 0x067B 
pid 0x2305
[ 5274.997679] usblp0: removed
[ 5522.007297] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 5561.914953] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 5681.101749] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 5782.969411] usb 1-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
```

EDIT: I checked the margins, and they are as default as the ones recommended in the answer. I changed the bottom margin slightly, but it always missed the bottom part of the  page when doing `Print Test Page`, at about 2cm to the end of the A4 page.

Comment: I think this problem has nothing to do with the parallel-USB adaptor, so I would rather delete this question and start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

In your browser open `CUPS`

cups -->administration-->deafault options-->adjustment

Change the values as follows:

Black ink density adjustment.:  2
Top Margin: 10
Bottom Margin:  150
Left Margin:    10
Right Margin:   10
Shift Output Horizontally:160
Shift Output Vertically: 50

I have had similar problem and this worked for `HEWLETT-PACKARD-DESKJET-720C` on `Ubuntu 12.04`.